# Invoking a REST API from BigQuery Query (PUT/POST)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am exploring ways to get some Data from BQ to another tool via POST/PUT methods.

Use case: we have some data integrity queries that periodically check if sums in one table, match sums in another table(s).

Ideally, we would like to post the result of this scheduled query to our Data Catalog tool (that has an API endpoint).

Any ways of doing that?

Thank you,
Dovile

**Update:**
Ok, got access  to run workflows. First of all wanted just to test and send a hardcoded sample. However, got stuck with a request body has a few Key Value Pairs.

**Workflow Code** what I got with the help of an evil friend Ch..

# This workflow makes an HTTP PUT request to an API endpoint with a JSON payload

```
main:
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
        - api_endpoint: "https://closed.abc.com/api/v1/testCase/fqn/testCaseResult"
        - auth_token: "token"
        - request_body:
            result: "Add a test case result data result"
            testCaseStatus: "Failed"
            testResultValue: 
              - name: "outliers A"
                value: "10"
              - name: "outliers B"
                value: "10"
              - name: "outliers C"
                value: "10"
            timestamp: 1679539970
        - request_headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
            Authorization: concat("Bearer ", $auth_token) 
      # Call the API endpoint with the payload 
    - post_message:
        call: http.put
        args:
          url: ${api_endpoint}
          headers: ${request_headers}
          body: ${request_body}
        result: the_message
    # Return the response body 
    - return_value:
        return: ${the_message.body}
```

With this code I get an

> *error can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 25, column 9: call: http.put*

**Ideally my request body (in JSON) would be**. This is what I am posting via Postman and it works. But not sure how can pass that as (haven't worked with YAML much or APIs. Looked in to this as well https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/http-requests#yaml_1

```
{
  "result": "Add a test case result data result",
  "testCaseStatus": "Failed",
  "testResultValue": [
    {
      "name": "outliers A",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "outliers B",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "outliers C",
      "value": "10"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 1679539970
}
```

Comment: yes, via Cloud Workflows. I have more tutorials covering BQ automation and external API as well https://martonkodok.medium.com/

Answer (score 1):

here's sample code that queries the bq tables and checks if results match. here for example, I am using count whereas you can change it if to sum in code

The code till - check-result is working. the code that follows is sample code to call external endpoint which is not working as I don't have external endpoint to test. hope this helps?

```
- init:
    assign:
    - project_id: "myproject"
    - bq_datasetset: "zz_DataSet"
    - bq_table_1: "tblOne"
    - bq_table_2: "tblTwo"
    - bq_query: "SELECT if(count(*)=1,true,false) as resultsFlag FROM ( SELECT count(1) as freq FROM `myproject.zz_DataSet.tblOne` UNION DISTINCT SELECT count(1) as freq FROM `myproject.zz_DataSet.tblTwo` );"

- bq-table-results:
    call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
    args:
        projectId: ${project_id}
        body:
            useLegacySql: false
            defaultDataset:
                datasetId: ${bq_datasetset}
                projectId: ${project_id}
            query: ${bq_query}
    result: queryResult
- check-result:
    return: ${queryResult}
- post_message:
    call: http.post
    assign:
    - bqResult: ${items[i].f[0].v}
    args:
      url: https://python.new
      body:
        language: python
    result: the_message
- return_value:
    return: ${the_message.body}
```

Comment: Oh. Very interesting! I will try that. Stupid question - where do you execute this code?

Comment: From the console, here are the steps. https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/executing-workflow

Comment: Ok, got access  to run workflows. First of all wanted just to test and send a hardcoded sample. However, got stuck with a request body has a few Key Value Pairs.

Comment: Updated the question as well